# make test subscribe in void

Tags: angular, jasmine

I want make a test with jasmine, I want test a function that have void type,and when I make a test using subscribe that have a problem
this is my function:

```
getMenu(): void {
    this.service.getMenuItems()
    .subscribe(navigation => {
      this.navigationModel = navigation.menu;//belum test
      console.log('test menu', this.navigationModel);
    });
}
```

i dont know how to test subscibe in void menu

Comment: Are you mocking the service? Have you read through https://angular.io/guide/testing?

Comment: is void can't test with subscribe?

Comment: Well you certainly can't subscribe to the result of calling a void method, because it's a void method, it doesn't return an observable.

Comment: so what I must do if I want test that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the values of objects that `subscribe` changes. Spy on `this.service.getMenuItems()`.

What you actually want to do here is to mock the behavior of your service, to return a fake value and test whether `this.navigationModel` is updated accordingly. You're not meant to test the service or its `getMenuItems` method. A sample code:

```
it('should change value on subscribe', () => {
  const fakeValue = {}; // your fake value
  spyOn(service, getMenuItems).and.callFake(
    () => asyncData(Object.assign({}, fakeValue)));

  component.getMenu();
  expect(component.navigationModel).toBe(fakeValue);
});
```

where `asyncData` is a utility function.

```
export function asyncData<T>(data: T) {
  return Observable.of(data);
}
```

A more detailed explanation: https://angular.io/guide/testing#provide-a-spy-stub-herodetailservicespy

Jasmine spies: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies

Comment: I got error in asyncData "cannot find name asyncData"

Comment: Sorry. Updated now. Basically it is a helper function that returns an observable of your fake value. You should be trying to mock the service method and return an observable. I'm not at liberty to produce a demo now but I hope you get the idea